# How to assign class static variables to control in aspx page?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have one static class with two property.

```
public class SiteDetails
{
    public static string MetaIndexKeyword { get; set; }
    public static string SiteName { get; set; }

}
```

And one default page where i need to assign these static value on page load.

```
<meta name="keywords" content='<%= DealCollector.Model.SiteDetails.MetaIndexKeyword %>' />
 <asp:Label id="test" runat="server" Text='<%= DealCollector.Model.SiteDetails.HtmlMetaKeyword %>'></asp:Label>
```

And Static class and Default page Namespaces are different.

When I am calling simply like this

```
<%= DealCollector.Model.SiteDetails.HtmlMetaKeyword %>
```

Then it working fine but in control and meta value it's not showing value.

please help me to find this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<%= expressions` cannot be used as properties, you have to use `<%# expressions` instead.

Since  `<%# expressions` are evaluated at `DataBind()` time, if you used that, then you need to call `DataBind();` method at `PreRenderComplete` like..

```
protected void Page_PreRenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```

Finally it will be like, if you set the property to your label control

```
Text='<%# DealCollector.Model.SiteDetails.HtmlMetaKeyword %>'
```